# React map function to create <Redirect> which carry wrong parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner in React.

A.js

```
const obj ={
  {name:objA, id:11111},
  {name:objB, id:22222},
};
const [isRedirect, setIsRedirect] = useState(false);


xxxxxxx.....................

return( 

   obj.map((data) => (
      <TableCell onClick = {setIsRedirect(true)}> 
           data.name 
       </TableCell>

   { isRedirect ?  

       
     <Redirect to={{ 
                                         
        pathname:'/user-management', 
                                          
        state:{userID:data.id},
     }}  />   : "" }
   )

 )
```

user-management.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const history = createHashHistory();
    if (history.location.state && history.location.state.transaction) 
    {
        let state = { ...history.location.state };
        delete state.transaction;
        history.replace({ ...history.location, state });
    }


     console.log(props.location.state.userID); // show 22222


 }
```

After I click the objA table cell,
The code in user-management.js executes,
but when I console.log(props.location.state),
It shows the user id as 22222 instead of 11111.
It seems props.location.state in user-management always stored the last value of json array obj.
How can I modify to code?
I would be grateful if u guys help.
And Sorry for the code structure.

Comment: What is `(set isRedirect to true)`? How is `data.id` set for the redirect state? Please include complete code.

Comment: @Drew Reese Updated. Appreciate if u can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably more going on, but I think the `onClick` handler should be `onClick={() => setIsRedirect(true)}`.

I see you are trying to render multiple `Redirect`s, but you've only a single `isRedirect` state. The *entire* component renders... every element you map. I suspect when once you toggle the `isRedirect` true that you probably get a redirect for every element mapped. They all redirect to the same path though, so the last redirect with data is the one you see.

## Suggestion

Only render one `Redirect` conditionally, and set `isRedirect` to be the `data.id` value (*assumes id's will always be truthy!!!*)

```
...

const [redirectId, setRedirectId] = useState(null);

...

if (redirectId) {
  return (
    <Redirect
      to={{                             
        pathname: '/user-management',      
        state: { userID: redirectId},
      }}
    />
  );
}

return obj.map((data) => (
  <TableCell onClick={() => setRedirectId(data.id)}> 
    {data.name}
  </TableCell>
);
```